# How do you target indexes of a string in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

I am working on a code challenge and I want to target odd and even indexes. I based my code off of the [W3 schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) and I can't even console log the for loop. However, when I try targeting an index in node it works fine. Here's my code:

```
let newString = ''
  for (let even, odd= 1; even < string.length; even + 2, odd + 2) {
    newString += string[even] + string[odd]
  }
console.log(newString)
```

Comment: Your code does not initialize `even` and does not increment either variable.

Comment: This won't work correctly (after fixing the already mentioned problems by Pointy) for strings with a length that is not even.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? If you fix those errors, it will just copy the string. Did you intend to swap the even and odd elements?

Comment: You're not getting `console.log()` because you have an infinite loop, since you never increment the variables. `even + 2` should be `even += 2`, and the same for `odd`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize both variables, not just `odd`.

You need to reassign the variables with the incremented values, otherwise you have an infinite loop.

```
let newString = '';
for (let even = 0, odd = 1; even < string.length; even += 2, odd += 2) {
    newString += string[even];
    if (odd < string.length) { // avoid incorrect result if string has odd length
        newString += string[odd];
    }
}
console.log(newString);
```

There isn't really a need for the `odd` variable, since it's always `even + 1`, but I left it in.

Answer (score 0):

This one is simpler, and incorporates suggestions made in above comments.

```
let newString = '';
  for (let even = 0; even < string.length - 1; even += 2) {
    newString += string[even] + string[even + 1];
  }
console.log(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code suggestion. Never forget to test for index range overflow, otherwise you get a pretty nasty 'undefined' at the end of your string hehehe.

```
let newString = '';

for (let index = 0; index < string.length; index+=2) {
    newString += string[index] + (string[index + 1] || '');
}

console.log(newString);
```